# "OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied" on vps but works fine on local system

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple socket server which receives request from a client application and then read the csv file and reply with the data from that csv file , on my local machine the below code works fine but when i upload this code to my windows based vps it gives **this error :**

> ```
> ServerSocket.listen(5) OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
> ```

**my code :**

```
import socket
import os
from _thread import *
import csv
ServerSocket = socket.socket()
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 25556
ThreadCount = 0
try:
    ServerSocket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))
print('Waitiing for a Connection..')
ServerSocket.listen(5)
def threaded_client(connection):
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        symbolrcvd = data.decode('utf-8')
        print (symbolrcvd);
        with open('MyRatios.csv') as csvfile:
            readval = {row['Symbol']: row for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile)}
            data1=readval[symbolrcvd]['Ratio']
        reply = data1
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    connection.close()
while True:
    Client, address = ServerSocket.accept()
    print('Connected to: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, ))
    ThreadCount += 1
    print('Thread Number: ' + str(ThreadCount))
ServerSocket.close()
```

**what could be causing this issue ?**

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: You are ignoring any socket errors; probably take out the `try`/`except` before this line completely at least until you understand what exactly is failing. Plunging ahead anyway when there was an error is a bug in its own right.